# UISegmenteControl UI not working properly

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

what may cause this problem in UISegmentedControl with an Extra line at the tail ? its all fine in preview and Designer but when it comes to running on phone its just not like it was , there isn't any other view near it and is just all it self , tried removing and putting another one without any customizations to its attributes and still the same , also I'm running this on ios 11

[image]

Comment: Using xcode "debug view hierarchy" show view hierarchy and find issue.

Comment: what is the backgroundColor of your UISegmentedControl

Comment: @Dix its shows just blank screen , not loading the views

Comment: @ankit clear color

Comment: @Moritz there is no code , dragged and dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I checked and it was gone nothing was changed dont know what caused the problem